# making adult content filter app in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-service, android-browser

i have made an browser in which it will not allow the user to see any adult content. i used only matcher and pattern something like this:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote("word which you want to block") + "\\b");
```

my question is:

Is it possible to filtering in whole android ?

for ex.: can i make a service of content filter which will work in back of every browser in android??

my idea is to get url from every browsers coz first i read whole contents of website and if my defined keywords will match with content then it will block the webpage otherwise it will not interrupt the user in surfing internet.

Comment: [A clbuttic mistake.](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx)

Comment: my boss gave me this project, if you know something then please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options:

- Block using `hosts` file(on rooted devices).
- Block in default Android browser(there are several apps on the market
  for that).

Comment: but if i use my code in default browser then how can i filter content on other browsers??  and how to block with hosts file?? will you please elaborate?

Comment: There's a lot of info about hosts on the Web. About third-party browsers - I guess the only way would be to look for their vulnerabilities. There's another way - if you're on wifi you can set proxy but that won't be invisible, I guess.